# impressive stable that he's got -- meaning?

Tags: comprehension

Example ([Putin Would Eat President Trump for Lunch](http://www.bloombergview.com/articles/2015-07-31/putin-would-eat-trump-for-lunch?cmpid=yhoo)):

> The Washington Post did its own comparison, pointing out that Trump's unfavorable rating in the U.S. is about as high as Putin's. Even Trump himself was once manipulated into comparing himself with Putin -- and he showed uncharacteristic humility: I've just heard for the first time that he has 40 planes and yachts and all that stuff, I mean, he has more than I do, that's some impressive list or **stable** that he's got.

What does he mean by *stable*? It doesn't sound like what he's saying about Putin has anything to do with horses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Stable* is commonly used metonymically for its inhabitants: we speak of a particular breeder's *stable* of racers. And this is widely extended to other sorts of brutes an owner keeps: a trainer's "stable" of boxers, a record publisher's "stable" of acts, a studio's "stable" of starlets.

Trump's use is thus fairly conservative: he metaphorically extends "stable" from biological transportation devices to mechanical ones.